# MySQL process won't die

Tags: windows, mysql, process

I am trying to delete the `mysqld.exe` file and it says:

> The action can't be completed because the file is open in mysql

I've tried to end the process, but it is stuck on "Starting", so I can't do anything.

Comment: Did you try restarting? Yeah, that's a stupid question but there are some things that only a reboot can fix.

Answer (score 3):

Set the service to "Manual" or "Disabled" in `services.msc` and then restart your computer.